# How can watch on google dataLayer object?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Is it possible to efectively watch on dataLayer changes in plain *JavaScript*? Everytime when is called dataLayer.push function i need to know about this adding and check event which was added to dataLayer. I cannot find any solution for this. I need somethin like `$watch` in *angularJS*, where you can observe changes on any object, but in this script, which i mensioned, I can use only plain *JS*. One sec interval infinite loop isn't good solution :) 
Thank you for hints, tips or advices.

I need somethink like:

```js
function callback() {
   // do the stuff with dataLayer
}
watch(window.dataLayer, callback);

window.dataLayer.push({event: 'any event', data: 'any data'});
window.dataLayer.push({event: 'any second event', data: 'any second data'});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could redefine the dataLayer.push function and combine it with custom events in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent

example:

```
var x = dataLayer.push; //make x equal to current datalayer function


dataLayer.push = function (myobj){

   x(myobj);//call current function

   alert('my event dispatch');//event dispatch code goes here
}
```